# sorting photos from every minute to every hour

Tags: timelapse, file-management

I have a data base of time lapse photos that have been taken for a period of a week, but i made a  newbies mistake and set the setting up for a photo every second, filled up my memory drive. Anyways my question is there a quicker way of sorting those photos on an hourly basis instead of 60 photos for every hr? to be more specific i only want the photos taken at for example 00:00:00 not 00:00:01, 00:00:20.. etc...
Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: Most of the decent photo managers can do this task. You folder\file renaming template should looks like: %YYYY\%mm\%year-%mm-%dd_%hh-%###, where %hhh is a counter that help you when you have several images taken within the same hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to lose the original file names, [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) has a very handy Multi-Rename tool for achieving that. Sort your files by ascending date (Ctrl-F5), select all (Ctrl+A), open the multi-rename dialog (Ctrl-M), enter **X[YMD][hm]** as the file name mask, and start the renaming process. The program will warn you that there would be duplicate names, and rename only the first file of each minute. After the rename, you can just sort by name; all the first photos within their minute will have a name starting with *X*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any software that could do this, but you could do this through the terminal/command prompt by writing a bash script. `grep` and regular expressions would be useful.